# git update submodule via windows batch file

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, command

I wrote a small batch file which updates the git submodules. My only problem is I want to review the changes after the git command but the command window closes - even if I add the "pause" command to it. See:

```
@echo off
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
pause
```

When I replace the whole `git` command with a simple `cd ..` it'll work as expected (waits for the user to hit enter) so my guess is that the git command does something I don't understand right now.

Thanks in advance!
krnl

Comment: Try to temporarily remove "@echo off" to see commands and try to execute it from opened console (to prevent closing window).

Comment: Ensure that there is git in PATH.

Comment: Thanks Vi. The problem was neither the echo nor a wrong/missing git path. The pause command simply failed. But thanks to Aacini below, the `call git ...` command solved the problem and the script now waits after execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the git command is a Batch file (git.bat) you must run it via a CALL command:

```
call git submodule foreach ....
```

Otherwise the original Batch file ends when the git.bat Batch file ends. The CALL command cause that when git.bat ends, the execution continue at the line after the CALL